# Making an interpolation function from data imported with SemanticImport

Tags: import, interpolation, dataset

I imported a list of data using

```
k = SemanticImport["Desktop/k_CARBON_eV.txt"]
```

[image]

And then I wanted to interpolate the data using:

```
kinter = Interpolation[k];
```

But I got a message:
[image]

Comment: Try with `ListInterpolation`

Comment: Try converting the `Dataset` to an array, maybe `Values /@ Normal@k`.  But you should really post code people can use to check solutions.

Comment: Related/duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/149060/cant-listplot-two-set-of-data

Comment: Why are you still working with SemanticImport if you can't handle it? It was suggested to you to try to import `"Table"` or `"Data"` couple of times, have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`k` is a dataset, which has head `Dataset`. `Interpolation` wants a list, typically a list of data pairs. To covert `k` to such, use `Normal`.

```
k = Dataset[{{5.88, .39}, {5.83, .41}, {5.73, .48}, {5.75, .58}}];
kinter = Interpolation[k // Normal];
Plot[kinter[x], Join[{x}, kinter["Domain"][[1]]]]
```

[image: plot]